# I get an error when running my discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new discord.Client();
Client.login("code");
```

And this is the error I get:

```js
ReferenceError: discord is not defined at Object.<anonymous>
```

Comment: i get this error ReferenceError: discord is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\keagan\desktop\DISCORDBOT\main.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Comment: Do you mean `const Client = new Discord.Client();` (Discord with a capital "D")? Also, please [edit] all information into the question itself.

Comment: ok so after me doing that ive now stumbled upon another issue so this is the code :const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client();




client.once('ready',  () => {
    console.log('MR_FAPPASS bot is online!')
});

client.login('code')

Comment: and now i have gotten this error : ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\keagan\desktop\DISCORDBOT\main.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client();
Client.login("<TOKEN>");
```

You did a smaller case "D" in `Discord.Client()`, causing discord to return undefined.